# Responsive Design for Image Slider Not as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

Hey guys I created an image slider but for some reason when I resize the browser the image for it messes up, the width is too small and the height stays the same, I'm stumped on what to do here
Here is the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjaxfnn8/8/

Below is an image of the slider normally and how it looks when browser is resized

[image: Here is the first image]

[image: Second Image]

HTML

```
<section id="slider">
  <ul class="mySlide">
    <li><img src="images/slider1.png" alt="Slider image"></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider2.png" alt="Slider image"></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider3.png" alt="Slider image"></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider4.png" alt="Slider image"></li>
  </ul>
<button class="prev">Back</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
//http://imageslidermaker.com/blog/how-to-make-a-responsive-image-slider-using-jquery-and-css
$(function() {
//Variables
  var ul = $("#slider ul"); 
  var slide_count = ul.children().length; // Count number of images
  var sliderDuration = 500; //Animation duration
  var slide_width_pc = 100.0 / slide_count; //width of each slide (100%) / slide count (4)
  var slide_index = 0; // Track first visible image

  ul.find("li").each(function(indx) { 
    var left_percent = (slide_width_pc * indx) + "%"; // Insert width of slider depending on number of images
    $(this).css({"left":left_percent});
    $(this).css({width:(100 / slide_count) + "%"}); // Insert width of slider depending on number of image
  });

  // Listen for click of prev button
  $("#slider .prev").click(function() {
    if(slide_index == 0){ //if user clicks previous on first image then,
        slide_index = slide_count; // transition to final image
    }
    slide(slide_index - 1); // -1 = previous image
  });

  // Listen for click of next button
  $("#slider .next").click(function() { 
     if((slide_count-1) == slide_index){  //if user clicks nexxt on last image then,
        slide_index = -1; // transition to first image (-1)
    }
    slide(slide_index + 1); // +1 = next image
  });

  function slide(new_slide_index) {
    var margin_left_pc = (new_slide_index * (-100)) + "%";
    ul.animate({"margin-left": margin_left_pc}, sliderDuration, function() { // slide image to the left of margin

      slide_index = new_slide_index // update to new index when changed

    });
  }
});
```

CSS

```
#slider {
  overflow: hidden; /* Hides images that are next or previous until button is pressed */
  height: 650px; /* Height of slider */
  position: relative; /* Position of slider */
}

#slider ul {
  position: absolute; /* Makes images not overlap*/
  width: 400%; /* Width of all images in slider */
  height: 100%;  /* Height of all images in slider */
}

#slider li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* Places slider from top */
  bottom: 0; /* Places slider from bottom */
}

#slider li img {
  width: 100%; /* Width of image in slider */
  min-height: 100%; /* Minimum height of image in slider */

}

#slider button {
  position: absolute; /* Moves button inside of the slider */
  border: none; /* Remove button border */
  top: 0; /* Button span from top down */
  bottom: 0; /* Button span from bottom up */
  width: 7%; /* Width of button */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  /* Background colour of button (transparent grey) */
  color: #fff; /* Colour of button text (white) */
}

#slider button.prev {
  left: 0; /* Move button to left */
}

#slider button.next {
  right: 0; /* Move button to right */
}

#slider button:hover, .slider button:active { /* If slider button is active and user hovers */
  opacity: 0.5; /* Decrease colour opacity by 0.5 */
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to change height in the css ?

Comment: Yes, it still does not work as intended. You can try it on JSFiddle if you like, it just creates a gap at the bottom

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you want aspect ratio maintained?

Comment: Yes, I just have no idea how

Answer (score 0):

You should use @media query for resize the height of your slider images.

Like:

```
 @media (max-width:500px) {
    #slider {
      overflow: hidden; /* Hides images that are next or previous until button is pressed */
      height: 350px; /* Adjust your height of slider */
      position: relative; /* Position of slider */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this works fine on the JSFiddle but on my website the images just enlarge to the screen and look huge